# QL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert a script from basic sql to pdo. I'm not so good at it, but i have come this far that my pdo returns all the rows in the database (limit 12) i can make 2 statements one without the limit and one with the limit. but in the sql that is originally there, it uses `QL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` what this does I think, is that i returns the total rows, and the limit rows, so that the query is faster.

How can i do it with PDO ?

CODE:

```
<?
// NORMAL SQL
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC limit 12');
$row_object = mysql_query('SELECT Found_Rows() AS rowcount');
$row_object = mysql_fetch_object($row_object);
$actual_row_count = $row_object->rowcount;

// PDO

$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC limit 12');
$result->execute();
$TOTALrows = $result->rowCount();

?>
```

EDIT:
Tried some things but this won't work:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC limit 12');
$result->execute();

$resultALL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT Found_Rows() AS rowcount');
$resultALL->execute();
$resultALL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$actual_row_count = $resultALL->rowcount;
```

EDIT2: Still no success..

```
    $result = $pdo->query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC limit 12');
$resultALL = $pdo->query('SELECT Found_Rows() AS rowcount');
$resultALL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$actual_row_count = $resultALL->rowcount;

print_r($actual_row_count);
echo $actual_row_count;
```

Doesn't echo anything.

Comment: Why don't you just use the same query with PDO?

Comment: How do you mean? My knowledge is not so big. do you mean to prepare a statement back in pdo but with `SELECT Found_Rows() AS rowcount`?

Comment: Edited my post with some new code!

Comment: I mean why don't you just do `$pdo->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM photos...`?

Comment: Check my edit! I've done some things there

Answer (score 0):

Credits also go to Explosion Pills here...

When you're not feeding your query with external input, you don't really have to prepare your statement:

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 12");
```

This should work!

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Doesn't echo anything:
I'll edit the script

Comment: Below said statement, put `$resultset = $result->fetchAll();`. Next, do `print_r($resultset);` to check if you get the proper results.

Comment: I've did it, and it just acts normal like i would type:
`$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC limit 12');`
So the rest isn't working. I was trying to make it as good as the normal mysql, that is twice faster ..